# Error when trying to activate Hyper-V feature, assembly not found

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I'm trying to install Docker but unfortunately Windows decided that I'm not going to do that. In order to get it working, I have to activate the Hyper-V feature. I tried using GUI and Powershell using the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName:Microsoft-Hyper-V` command but
[everything I get is this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5uUw.png) The referenced assembly could not be found. Error 0x80073701. How do I fix that? Thanks!

PS: My computer can run Hyper-V and the relative options are activated. Windows version is Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

Comment: Use the current LTSB ISO as a source

Comment: Excuse me, what do you mean?

Comment: You can indicate you want to use an mounted .wim as a source to install the feature your trying to install

Comment: Okay, I mounted my OS iso and went through this guide https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2913316/you-can-t-install-features-in-windows-server-2012-r2 thinking it could work on Windows 10 too but... powershell returns "The target of the specified cmdlet cannot be a Windows client-based operating system."

Comment: Tried also with the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` command but "The referenced assembly could not be found."

Comment: Try *dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V /All* and specify the source if it doesn’t work.  Outside of that specify your hardware so we can confirm it supports VT-x

Comment: Mount the current LTSB iso, then, dism /online /enable-feature /featurename:microsoft-hyper-v-all /All /LimitAccess /Source:C:\sources\sxs but change “C” to the drive letter of the mounted ISO

Comment: Yeah, I tried this as well but it says that the referenced assembly could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Evidently my system lacked some updates. I mounted the Windows ISO file and ran the `setup.exe` contained in the root directory. I let it do its stuff and then I could activate Hyper-V.